# Synchronized database access across Django processes

Tags: python, mysql, django, synchronization

Suppose I have 2 processes. One is a python Twisted service that runs continuously and that runs in a virtual environment with the ability to use Django models on top of a MYSQL database. This persistent process (called P1) will periodically receive a command to update two separate database tables - we'll call the associated models Event and Device. Also, once every minute or so, a separate process (we will call it P2) is run a s a cron job. P2 needs to get access to the Event and Device model data in a synchronized manner. So, in other words, I want to synchronize database access so that P1 updates Event and Device in a synchronized manner and P2 reads the information from the database tables for Event and Device in a synchronized manner. I am using Django version 1.4. So how can I do this?